# The mentioned HTML and JS code working in chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, runatserver

```js
function textcomment() 
{
           commentf.value = document.getElementById('chkComm').value;}
```

```html
   <asp:Label ID="llbcom" runat="server" CssClass="NormalSmallText" AssociatedControlID="chkComm" Visible="False">Reason for Request<FONT class="Asterisk" >*</FONT></asp:Label>

  <asp:TextBox ID="chkComm" runat="server" CssClass="NormalSmallText" onchange="textcomment();"
                        Width="100%" Rows="4" Visible="False" textmode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        

<input id="commentf" type="hidden" name="commentf" runat="server" />
```

Comment: haring your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Displaying the text box value in the grid

Comment: I am using IE 11 version

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to make a test with an example below. It is working fine in the IE 11 browser.

Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        var getVal = document.getElementById('<%= txt_id.ClientID %>').value;        
        document.getElementById('t1').value = getVal;
        alert(document.getElementById('t1').value);
    }
    </script>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_id" runat="server" onChange="getValue()" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
      <br />
     <input type="hidden" id="t1" value="123">
</asp:Content>
```

Output:

[image]